# Black screen after CPU upgrade

Tags: display, cpu, upgrade

So I have been wondering around for an answer to my problem but nothing quite fits.

I have a good 'ol HPg62 and I upgraded the CPU from the factory P6000 to a core i5 that I have salvaged from a Asus k55-vm.

The fan starts up but the screen is just stillborn.

I wanted to flash the BIOS or upgrade it but since the screen is dead I can't do anything.

Comment: You need to put the old CPU in then upgrade the firmware that might work but you didn't provide enough info to identify the processor

Comment: thats what I've thought. Are you talking about the P6000 or the i5?

Comment: Intel® Core™ i5-3210M Dual Core (Ivy Bridge).

Btw, my  OS is ubuntu gmome willy 4.2.0-27

Comment: I will anyway downgrade it to the factory settings. I'll let you good people know if it works (since this way we can discard that the bios or the motherboard are malfunctioning).

Answer (score 1):

After thinking and tweaking for a bit I came to a conclusion:

The G62 has a 32 bit bus, the Intel® Core™ i5-3210M Dual Core (Ivy Bridge) has a 64bit bus. Therefore the i5 is incompatible with the g62 motherboard.

Kinda feeling like a complete idiot.

Comment: Not an idiot but more of a geek that likes to experiment. Show me a person that has never make a mistake and I will show you a person that has never done anything.

Comment: @Moab :) Great and wisdom full words. Feeling like a mad doc then XD